# How do I turn off auto correction?

Tags: openoffice

When typing text in a spreadsheet I don't want the program to change anything I write in a cell. Eg "IEx" should not be translated to "Iex".

Answer (score 1):

To change this setting you must go to Tools > Auto Correct Options and in the option tab you must uncheck "Correct TWo INitial CApitals"

[image: Correct TWo INitial CApitals]